# Perceptions on a slightly differnt terrestrial planet

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-earth

What would be the perception for a human being on a planet with an axial deviation identical to the terrestrial one, but with a surface temperature of 292 K, a temperature range between 288 K - 310 K and an average atmospheric pressure of 1,14 atmospheres? Would it be a colder or hotter planet than Earth? Would it be habitable at all?

Comment: What do you mean with perception? are you aware that Earth has not a single unified temperature and that even the feeling of cold or hot  and in general thermal comfort is highly subjective? And also, converting your temperatures to the same units gives a nonsense (the average is above max and min)

Comment: Sorry. I'll try to explain my question better. I want to know if the surface temperature that I stated (292°K) is higher or lower than Earth's. If it's higher or lower, how it would be perceived? Would it generate colder winters on arctic and subarctic zones than Earth's? What effects would it have on our standard human biology an slightly higher average atmospheric pressure (1,14 atm.)? Would it generate mutations on a longer term?

Comment: I don't know about the whole Earth, but in Bucharest surface temperature (by which I mean the temperature of the air near the surface) varies between 260 K (or even less!) at night in January and 310 K (or even more!) at noon in July. And 1.14 atm is nothing to write home about; I seriously doubt that anybody would notice anything out of the ordinary without measurement equipment.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Jano Moore, you may need to clarify your question. Are you asking about thermal perception, i.e., is the planet hot or cold from a human perspective? if your humans are native to the planet, they could be adapted to its conditions. After all, humans on Earth will find different parts of our planet either too hot or too cold Have fun here!

Comment: -1 for not doing basic research firsr. Conversion from Kelvin to Celsius is straight addition. The first hit in Google is an online k to c calculator.

Answer (score 2):

#### Pressure

A pressure of 1.14 atm is equivalent to the pressure about 1.4 meters underwater. I know I've been that deep in a swimming pool (and the ocean!) before, so I don't think that this pressure is critical to human existence. I'm sure your ears would pop weirdly before you go used to it, but you can experimentally verify that you can still hear underwater.

#### Temperature

288K to 310 K is 15 to 37 C. Lagos, Nigeria, home to 10 million+ people, has an record annual range of 11 to 40 C. Other giant tropical cities (Chennai, Jakarta, Manilla, etc) will show similar temperature rages. Therefore, I conclude that your temperature range is perfectly amenable to human life.